# How to create a 3 column image grid using html and css?

Tags: html, css, grid, image-gallery

I am interested to know what is the best practice to create an image grid similar to the image attached using HTML and CSS.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: CSS columns, inline blocks, floating blocks, a table, flex boxes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use CSS flex container like so.

Here is sample CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  flex-direction:row;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  align-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  order: 1;  
}
```

Here is sample HTML to go with it:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div> 
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 4</div> 
</div>
```

You will need to take this technique and apply it your circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to create the grid view but I can't seem to align the items centre. 

http://imgur.com/j4Hrkf7

Comment: Post your code as a new question so the community can take a look it.  I am sure we can solve it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093444/how-to-center-align-a-grid-of-divs-in-a-flex-container

Comment: Is there a reason the height on the `.flex-container` div has to be 100px? I tested out the code and it seems to break the example. I think if you removed that line it would look more like the picture.