# How to Center elements in column with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been recently working on a website using Wordpress. I am trying to center html elements on a page. I have tried using padding and margins, but still no success.

Current Page:
[Using Current HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdK13.jpg)

Easiest Solution
[Basic Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll5Be.jpg)

Wanted Outcome
[Wanted Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUUSK.jpg)

I cant make these changes without affecting the look on a mobile device.

Here is the link to the website for additional help.
[https://landmark-re-service-llc.com/](https://landmark-re-service-llc.com/sale/)

I can't post the CSS or HTML so it will have to be inspected on webpage. due to character limitation:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093444/how-to-center-align-a-grid-of-divs-in-a-flex-container

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You may also be interested in the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal centering of elements in CSS is fairly easy. Assuming your centered elements are wrapped in a div, which should be centered within its parent element, this should work (using flexbox):

```
.parent-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I recommend using this rather than `margin: auto`, since it's easy to vertically center (`align-items: center`), as well as short. It also doesn't require any CSS for the wrapper div, saving time and space.