# Use flexbox to horizontally align images, maintainin aspect ratio, and scale to a mobile device while centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to use CSS3 flexbox to align three images horizontally while responsively changing the width of the picture being displayed. It needs to dynamically resize and center on a mobile device. I have found several [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077309/how-to-create-a-3-column-image-grid-using-html-and-css).

I have come up with two incomplete approaches as follows:

1. [This](https://codepen.io/appletechy/pen/zpjjQv) works to align them horizontally, but the issue is one of the images has a different height and I am not sure how to make it auto-size. I want that image to preserve its ratio but take up the same with. I also don't know what approach to take to make it center all the images on mobile, other than using a media query and having it `float:center`. In practice I couldn't get that to work.
2. My [other idea](https://codepen.io/appletechy/pen/YYLLor) was to create an image grid of sorts. I couldn't figure out how to get them to align correctly, even on desktop. I would want the individual ration of the images to be preserved, but have them take up 1/3 of the window width and resize the image as necessary dependent on the window width. Once it reaches 480px width, center the images with each the same width but still preserving its individual proportion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With object-fit and flex-aligning the elements to the elements to center, you can have them all aligned no matter the image ration, then for mobile it would be only matter of changing the flex-item width to 50%, 100%, or whatever you want with @media query

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box ;
}

.flex-container {
  background: darkred;
  flex-direction:row;
  display: flex;

  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 33.33%;
  order: 1;  
}

.flex-item img{
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://alumni.csum.edu/image/content/emails/TellMeSomethingGood.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://kyuyoungshipperindo.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/something.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://alumni.csum.edu/image/content/emails/TellMeSomethingGood.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://kyuyoungshipperindo.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/something.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://kyuyoungshipperindo.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/something.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="http://www.sypte.co.uk/uploadedImages/Media/Press_Releases/see%20something.JPG" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://alumni.csum.edu/image/content/emails/TellMeSomethingGood.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="http://www.sypte.co.uk/uploadedImages/Media/Press_Releases/see%20something.JPG" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. For one of the items I want it to have the 33.333% width but how do I also set a max height.(The image is very tall compared to the others. I tried adding a max-width to the item and it wasn't affecting the image at all. Any advice?